# Ставится ли запятая перед "и" при перечислении?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть такое предложение:
Карибское море, пляжи на любой вкус, простота местных, неиссякаемый позитив и немного магии. 
Нашелся человек, который считает, что перед "и" должна быть запятая.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Человек? Мутант он... после "Карибское море" просится НЕ запятая, если пачеснаку

Answer (score 3):

Мне понятно, что хотел Ваш "человек" - паузу перед "и немного магии", потому что в конкретном и реальном ряду перечислений возникает неожиданное, нетипичное.

И очень хорошо, что он чувствует паузу, только вместо запятой для воплощения замысла следует поставить многоточие:

*Карибское море, пляжи на любой вкус, простота местных жителей, неиссякаемый позитив и... немного магии.*

Answer (score 1):

Это **односоставные (назывные) предложения,**  которые   практически **приравниваются  к однородным членам**, поэтому запятая между ними при наличии одиночных союзов И,  ДА, ИЛИ, ЛИБО также не ставится:

Шум и хохот. Мороз и солнце. Глухая ночь и  вьюга. Ночь, лес и снег. Дождь или мокрый снег.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая при перечислениях ставится только в особых случаях, например, при повторяющихся союзах "и". Здесь ничего особенного нет, и запятая не нужна. При простом перечислении запятая в этом месте может ставиться в американском английском ("оксфордская запятая" - по рекомендации одного из издательств) - не американец ли тот человек?